# How to use a list of jinja templates store in a YML file with a Playbook?

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I need help because i'm stuck since 2 days with a playbook.

First of all, i have a YAML file which contains **jinja templates** :

```
---
template lab:
 - first_template.j2
 - second_template.j2
 - third_template.j2
```

It exists a YAML file which have value for each router, stores in **"./yml/{{ inventory_hostname }}.yml"**

I have a playbook Ansible which needs to use jinja templates for generate a **.conf** file.

```
---
- name: Generate .conf file
  hosts: my_routers
  gather_facts: no
  vars: 
  - jinja_templates: "{{ (lookup('template', './template_list.yml') | from_yaml).template_lab }}"
  vars_files: 
  - "./yml/{{ inventory_hostname }}.yml"
  
  tasks:
    - name: test
      debug:
        msg: "{{ jinja_templates }}"
    - name: Generate configuration files
      template:
        src: "./templates/{{ jinja_templates }}"
        dest: "./tmp/general/{{ inventory_hostname }}.conf"
        mode: "0644"
```

**OUTPUT of the playbook when i play it :**

```
Could not find or access './templates/['first_template.j2', 'second_template.j2', 'third_template'.j2']'
```

**1 :** The first issue is that **{ jinja_templates }}** output contains "[" "]" and "'" "'", so it is impossible for Ansible to use the Jinja Templates.

**2 :** How can i do an interation for use all jinja templates and generate configuration in a single file ?

I know that i don't use the correct structure of Ansible' Playbook ! It is for the moment experimental test **:)**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the template files names as one line:

```yaml
- debug:
   msg: "{{ jinja_templates }}"
```

The output is being an array:

```yaml
TASK [test] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "first_template.j2",
        "second_template.j2",
        "third_template.j2"
    ]
}
```

**You should loop over it to get them as single values:**

```yaml
- debug:
   msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ jinja_templates }}"
```

```yaml
TASK [test] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=first_template.j2) => {
    "msg": "first_template.j2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=second_template.j2) => {
    "msg": "second_template.j2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=third_template.j2) => {
    "msg": "third_template.j2"
}
```

Besides that you defined the same destination file in your template task `dest: "./tmp/general/{{ inventory_hostname }}.conf"`.
That would lead to only writing the last template file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it help me a lot ! Is it possible to write all template Jinja result in a single file ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't take attention to the single file request in the question. In this case the answer of Vladimir Botka ist the right one, because I'll also do it the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***"Use all jinja templates and generate configuration in a single file."***

A: Iterate the list of templates and create [*content*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#parameter-content). For example, given the tree

```
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
├── template_list.yml
└── templates
    ├── first_template.j2
    ├── second_template.j2
    └── third_template.j2
```

```
shell> cat hosts
[my_routers]
test_11
test_12
test_13
```

```yaml
shell> cat template_list.yml
template_list:
  - first_template.j2
  - second_template.j2
  - third_template.j2
```

```yaml
shell> cat templates/first_template.j2 
Content of the 1 template.

shell> cat templates/second_template.j2 
Content of the 2 template.

shell> cat templates/third_template.j2 
Content of the 3 template.
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: my_routers
  vars_files:
    template_list.yml
  tasks:
    - copy:
        dest: "/tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}.conf"
        content: |
          {% for file in template_list %}
          {{ lookup('template', file) }}
          {%- endfor %}
```

will create the files

```yaml
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /tmp/test_11.conf
Content of the 1 template.
Content of the 2 template.
Content of the 3 template.

shell> ssh admin@test_12 cat /tmp/test_12.conf
Content of the 1 template.
Content of the 2 template.
Content of the 3 template.

shell> ssh admin@test_13 cat /tmp/test_13.conf
Content of the 1 template.
Content of the 2 template.
Content of the 3 template.
```

Comment: Hello :) Sorry, i forgot to thank you. Your answer works and solve my issue. Really really thanks !